# My project Vue 3 vuelidate sameAs not wokring

Tags: validation, vuejs3

I'm working on a project written in vue 3 and I want to validate it on the login page but `sameAs validate` not working:

```
  <div class="row">
        <label for="password">Şifrə təkrarla</label>
        <input
          @blur="v$.repassword.$touch()"
          v-model.lazy="repassword"
          type="text"
          name="repassword"
          v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': !v$.repassword.$invalid }"
          placeholder="********"
        />
        
        <small class="validate_message" v-if="!v$.repassword.sameAs.$response"
          >Yuxarıda yazdığınız şifrə ilə üst-üstə düşmür.</small
        >
      </div>
```

**My script:**

```
<script>
import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
import { sameAs } from "@vuelidate/validators";

export default {
  setup() {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      repassword: "",
    };
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      repassword: {
        sameAs: sameAs(function() {
          return this.password;
        }),
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```